# How to add image on canvas using javascript if the canvas already has an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have an image on canvas; the image is not uploading on canvas.

I need to display that old image. Below is the code that I have tried so far:

```
$("#ImageUpload").uploadify({
            'multi': false,
            'queueSizeLimit': 1,
            'fileSizeLimit': 0,
            'progressData': 'speed',
            'swf': 'upscripts/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader': 'ImageUpload.ashx?value=a',
            'cancelImg': 'upscripts/uploadify-cancel.png',
            'buttonImage': 'DesignFiles/images/upload.png',
            'width': 67,
            'height': 50,
            'folder': 'Uploads',
            'auto': true,

            'onUploadError': function (file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {


            },
            'onUploadSuccess': function (file, response) {

                var a = file.name;
                var b = "asdfd";
                angular.element("#canvascontainer").scope().InsertImage(a);

            }
        });
```

Comment: "I have an image on canvas" >> "the image is not uploading on canvas" >> "I need to display that old image" >> @_@

Comment: yes please try and make the question clear

Comment: above code is not working for i m trying to uploading image on to canvas but in there is already one image is there